# Econ literature recommendations on Health Policy Evaluation

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, health-economics

I am writing a methodological paper on public policy evaluation in the context of child health outcomes. Particularly in Africa, multiple policies are launched simultaneously trying to improve child health outcomes, principally reducing child mortality through vaccination drives, diarrhoea reduction, doctor's visits etc. But all the papers I see evaluate individual policies, one at a time, in isolation. I feel like a lot of the estimates are biased given that often there are two or more policies working in tandem targeting the same population, and the same outcomes at the same time.

Are there any econ studies that I can refer to where they evaluate two or more policies at the same time? All I see is the aforementioned ones where one policy's impact is studied in isolation with no regard for the existing policy environment. This is even more so the case when I delve into public health literature.

Comment: Most of the research in this area is causal research, so the authors in the papers you're reading would have justified why they believe the policy/intervention they are evaluating has a causal effect on the dependent variable. The "policy environment" is stuff that would be captured in the error term and the authors would usually correct for any omitted variable bias based on the policy environment if they believe there is some.